# How do I access a viewmodel that's nested within a namespace\module path?

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#

How do I access a viewmodel that's nested within a namespace\module path?

**Example:**

```
namespace ManageModules
module CreateModule =
   ...
    type CreationViewModel() =
        inherit ViewModelBase()
```

**The following namespace declaration gets resolved:**

```
xmlns:manageModules="clr-namespace:ManageModules;assembly=ManageModules"
```

**Within the following XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
        . . .
        xmlns:manageModules="clr-namespace:ManageModules;assembly=ManageModules"
        . . . />

    <Window.DataContext>
        <manageModules:CreationViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

**Issue:**

Note how my viewmodel is not directly under the namespace, but instead a namespace\module path.

**Example:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <manageModules:CreationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

**This does not work:**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <manageModules:CreateModule.CreationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

As a result, I am having trouble setting the DataContext because providing the the namespace is not enough to identify the viewmodel path.

**Error:**

> The name "CreationViewModel" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:ManageModules;assembly=ManageModules".

**My ViewModel is the following:**

```
namespace ManageModules
module CreateModule =

    open System.Windows.Input
    open UILogic.State
    open UILogic.Interaction
    open ManageModule.Entities
    open System.Collections.ObjectModel

    type CreationViewModel() =
        inherit ViewModelBase()

        let mutable (_modules:Module ObservableCollection) = ObservableCollection()

        member this.Modules
            with get()      = _modules
            and set(value)  = _modules <- value

        member this.Add moduleItem = 
            _modules.Add(moduleItem)
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at the compiled assembly with Reflection, or a decompiler, in order to learn what the type names are?

Comment: @ Mark Seeman - Good idea!

Comment: I found a solution on my blog. In my article, I only had namespace. Hence, I did not declare a module. https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/mvvm-with-f-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the module declaration from the ViewModel.

**So remove this line:**

```
module CreateModule =
```

**And just keep the rest of the code:**

```
namespace ManageModules

    open System.Windows.Input
    open UILogic.State
    open UILogic.Interaction
    open ManageModule.Entities
    open System.Collections.ObjectModel

    type CreationViewModel() =
        inherit ViewModelBase()
        let name =      { First=String20("Scott"); Last=String20("Nimrod"); Suffix=None }
        let duration =  { Hours=1; Minutes=30; Seconds=0 }
        let moduleItem = { Author=name; Duration=duration }

        let mutable (_modules:Module ObservableCollection) = ObservableCollection()

        do _modules.Add(moduleItem)

        member this.Modules
            with get()      = _modules
            and set(value)  = _modules <- value

        member this.Add moduleItem = 
            _modules.Add(moduleItem)
```